# How to upload files to Office 365 by using cURL command from Linux

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, linux

I tried the below to upload file to sharepoint(office 365), but the file is not getting loaded. Please help.

```
curl -T “test_file.xls” -o “test_file.xls” -u “nikhil.viswanathan@wincshare.onmicrosoft.com” “https://wincshare.sharepoint.com/Test/”
```

Enter host password for user ‘nikhil.viswanathan@wincshare.onmicrosoft.com':
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 26 0 13 0 13 15 15 –:–:– –:–:– –:–:– 78

I'm facing this issue in office 365.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this problem?